# TFS: How can i merge same changeset to target branch again/multiple time

Tags: tfs, merge, rollback, changeset

I have two branch on TFS
1. SourceBranch 
2. TargetBranch

My Working copy is SourceBranch. Now there are 5 Changeset in my SourceBranch
Chset01, Chset02, Chset03, Chset04, Chset05 which i wanted to merge in TargetBranch.

I have selected all above five Changeset and merged into TargetBranch and commit it.So there is only single changeset history in Targetbranch. i don't know which file for which changeset and task.

Now, I wanted changeset history in TargetBranch as well like wise Chset06, Chset07..Chset10.

Will I able to merge all five changeset again in TargetBranch one by one? How? I won't be able to see all five changeset while am going to merge it again. will it be appear if i rollback from TargetBranch?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can force the merge of an already merged changeset using tf.exe.  Drop to a command prompt and locate tf.exe.  For example, mine is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe
```

The syntax will look like this (for tfvc):

```
tf.exe vc merge /version:C1 /force "$/RepositoryName/SourceBranch/FileName" "$/RepositoryName/TargetBranch/FileName"
```

...where **/version:C*n*** specifies the changeset number.

Keep in mind though, you must merge each file individually.  Also, if the destination code hasn't changed since the initial merge you will not see any changes with a forced merge.  If you want the history to reflect each merged changeset individually, or if you don't want to re-merge each file, your only other option is to rollback the initial merge, and then re-merge each changeset separately.